# Content Security Policy: Couldn't parse invalid source chrome-extension

Tags: firefox, facebook-javascript-sdk, content-security-policy

I'm getting a new error in my JS console on Firefox and I haven't changed the code.
I don't get this error in other browsers and doesn't seem to affect the functionality of my code.
It's obviously in some way related to Firefox, but it seems to be pointing the error out to my async loaded facebook JS SDK.

Anybody else using that SDK seeing this in Firefox now? Any help or insight?
This is the full message:
   Content Security Policy: Couldn't parse invalid source chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl

and this is the line in the fb JS SDK:

```
*/__d("JSON3",[],function(a,b,c,d,e,f){(function(){var g={}.toString,h,i,j,k=e.exports={},l='{"A":[1,true,false,null,"\\u0000\\b\\n\\f\\r\\t"]}',m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,aa,ba=new Date(-3509827334573292),ca,da,ea;try{ba=ba.getUTCFullYear()==-109252&&ba.getUTCMonth()===0&&ba.getUTCDate()==1&&ba.getUTCHours()==10&&ba.getUTCMinutes()==37&&ba.getUTCSeconds()==6&&ba.getUTCMilliseconds()==708;}catch(fa){}if(!ba){ca=Math.floor;da=[0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334];ea=function(ga,ha){return da[ha]+365*(ga-1970)+ca((ga-1969+(ha=+(ha>1)))/4)-ca((ga-1901+ha)/100)+ca((ga-1601+ha)/400);};}if(typeof JSON=="object"&&JSON){k.stringify=JSON.stringify;k.parse=JSON.parse;}if((m=typeof k.stringify=="function"&&!ea)){(ba=function(){return 1;}).toJSON=ba;try{m=k.stringify(0)==="0"&&k.stringify(new Number())==="0"&&k.stringify(new String())=='""'&&k.stringify(g)===j&&k.stringify(j)===j&&k.stringify()===j&&k.stringify(ba)==="1"&&k.stringify([ba])=="[1]"&&k.stringify([j])=="[null]"&&k.stringify(null)=="null"&&k.stringify([j,g,null])=="[null,null,null]"&&k.stringify({result:[ba,true,false,null,"\0\b\n\f\r\t"]})==l&&k.stringify(null,ba)==="1"&&k.stringify([1,2],null,1)=="[\n 1,\n 2\n]"&&k.stringify(new Date(-8.64e+15))=='"-271821-04-20T00:00:00.000Z"'&&k.stringify(new Date(8.64e+15))=='"+275760-09-13T00:00:00.000Z"'&&k.stringify(new Date(-62198755200000))=='"-000001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"'&&k.stringify(new Date(-1))=='"1969-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"';}catch(fa){m=false;}}if(typeof k.parse=="function")try{if(k.parse("0")===0&&!k.parse(false)){ba=k.parse(l);if((r=ba.A.length==5&&ba.A[0]==1)){try{r=!k.parse('"\t"');}catch(fa){}if(r)try{r=k.parse("01")!=1;}catch(fa){}}}}catch(fa){r=false;}ba=l=null;if(!m||!r){if(!(h={}.hasOwnProperty))h=function(ga){var ha={},ia;if((ha.__proto__=null,ha.__proto__={toString:1},ha).toString!=g){h=function(ja){var ka=this.__proto__,la=ja in (this.__proto__=null,this);this.__proto__=ka;return la;};}else{ia=ha.constructor;h=function(ja){var ka=(this.constructor||ia).prototype;return ja in this&&!(ja in ka&&this[ja]===ka[ja]);};}ha=null;return h.call(this,ga);};i=function(ga,ha){var ia=0,ja,ka,la,ma;(ja=function(){this.valueOf=0;}).prototype.valueOf=0;ka=new ja();for(la in ka)if(h.call(ka,la))ia++;ja=ka=null;if(!ia){ka=["valueOf","toString","toLocaleString","propertyIsEnumerable","isPrototypeOf","hasOwnProperty","constructor"];ma=function(na,oa){var pa=g.call(na)=="[object Function]",qa,ra;for(qa in na)if(!(pa&&qa=="prototype")&&h.call(na,qa))oa(qa);for(ra=ka.length;qa=ka[--ra];h.call(na,qa)&&oa(qa));};}else if(ia==2){ma=function(na,oa){var pa={},qa=g.call(na)=="[object Function]",ra;for(ra in na)if(!(qa&&ra=="prototype")&&!h.call(pa,ra)&&(pa[ra]=1)&&h.call(na,ra))oa(ra);};}else ma=function(na,oa){var pa=g.call(na)=="[object Function]",qa,ra;for(qa in na)if(!(pa&&qa=="prototype")&&h.call(na,qa)&&!(ra=qa==="constructor"))oa(qa);if(ra||h.call(na,(qa="constructor")))oa(qa);};return ma(ga,ha);};if(!m){n={"\\":"\\\\",'"':'\\"',"\b":"\\b","\f":"\\f","\n":"\\n","\r":"\\r","\t":"\\t"};o=function(ga,ha){return ("000000"+(ha||0)).slice(-ga);};p=function(ga){var ha='"',ia=0,ja;for(;ja=ga.charAt(ia);ia++)ha+='\\"\b\f\n\r\t'.indexOf(ja)>-1?n[ja]:ja<" "?"\\u00"+o(2,ja.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)):ja;return ha+'"';};q=function(ga,ha,ia,ja,ka,la,ma){var na=ha[ga],oa,pa,qa,ra,sa,ta,ua,va,wa,xa,ya,za,ab,bb,cb;if(typeof na=="object"&&na){oa=g.call(na);if(oa=="[object Date]"&&!h.call(na,"toJSON")){if(na>-1/0&&na<1/0){if(ea){ra=ca(na/86400000);for(pa=ca(ra/365.2425)+1970-1;ea(pa+1,0)<=ra;pa++);for(qa=ca((ra-ea(pa,0))/30.42);ea(pa,qa+1)<=ra;qa++);ra=1+ra-ea(pa,qa);sa=(na%86400000+86400000)%86400000;ta=ca(sa/3600000)%24;ua=ca(sa/60000)%60;va=ca(sa/1000)%60;wa=sa%1000;}else{pa=na.getUTCFullYear();qa=na.getUTCMonth();ra=na.getUTCDate();ta=na.getUTCHours();ua=na.getUTCMinutes();va=na.getUTCSeconds();wa=na.getUTCMilliseconds();}na=(pa<=0||pa>=10000?(pa<0?"-":"+")+o(6,pa<0?-pa:pa):o(4,pa))+"-"+o(2,qa+1)+"-"+o(2,ra)+"T"+o(2,ta)+":"+o(2,ua)+":"+o(2,va)+"."+o(3,wa)+"Z";}else na=null;}else if(typeof na.toJSON=="function"&&((oa!="[object Number]"&&oa!="[object String]"&&oa!="[object Array]")||h.call(na,"toJSON")))na=na.toJSON(ga);}if(ia)na=ia.call(ha,ga,na);if(na===null)return "null";oa=g.call(na);if(oa=="[object Boolean]"){return ""+na;}else if(oa=="[object Number]"){return na>-1/0&&na<1/0?""+na:"null";}else if(oa=="[object String]")return p(na);if(typeof na=="object"){for(ab=ma.length;ab--;)if(ma[ab]===na)throw TypeError();ma.push(na);xa=[];bb=la;la+=ka;if(oa=="[object Array]"){for(za=0,ab=na.length;za<ab;cb||(cb=true),za++){ya=q(za,na,ia,ja,ka,la,ma);xa.push(ya===j?"null":ya);}return cb?(ka?"[\n"+la+xa.join(",\n"+la)+"\n"+bb+"]":("["+xa.join(",")+"]")):"[]";}else{i(ja||na,function(db){var eb=q(db,na,ia,ja,ka,la,ma);if(eb!==j)xa.push(p(db)+":"+(ka?" ":"")+eb);cb||(cb=true);});return cb?(ka?"{\n"+la+xa.join(",\n"+la)+"\n"+bb+"}":("{"+xa.join(",")+"}")):"{}";}ma.pop();}};k.stringify=function(ga,ha,ia){var ja,ka,la,ma,na,oa;if(typeof ha=="function"||typeof ha=="object"&&ha)if(g.call(ha)=="[object Function]"){ka=ha;}else if(g.call(ha)=="[object Array]"){la={};for(ma=0,na=ha.length;ma<na;oa=ha[ma++],((g.call(oa)=="[object String]"||g.call(oa)=="[object Number]")&&(la[oa]=1)));}if(ia)if(g.call(ia)=="[object Number]"){if((ia-=ia%1)>0)for(ja="",ia>10&&(ia=10);ja.length<ia;ja+=" ");}else if(g.call(ia)=="[object String]")ja=ia.length<=10?ia:ia.slice(0,10);return q("",(oa={},oa[""]=ga,oa),ka,la,ja,"",[]);};}if(!r){s=String.fromCharCode;t={"\\":"\\",'"':'"',"/":"/",b:"\b",t:"\t",n:"\n",f:"\f",r:"\r"};u=function(){z=aa=null;throw SyntaxError();};v=function(){var ga=aa,ha=ga.length,ia,ja,ka,la,ma;while(z<ha){ia=ga.charAt(z);if("\t\r\n ".indexOf(ia)>-1){z++;}else if("{}[]:,".indexOf(ia)>-1){z++;return ia;}else if(ia=='"'){for(ja="@",z++;z<ha;){ia=ga.charAt(z);if(ia<" "){u();}else if(ia=="\\"){ia=ga.charAt(++z);if('\\"/btnfr'.indexOf(ia)>-1){ja+=t[ia];z++;}else if(ia=="u"){ka=++z;for(la=z+4;z<la;z++){ia=ga.charAt(z);if(!(ia>="0"&&ia<="9"||ia>="a"&&ia<="f"||ia>="A"&&ia<="F"))u();}ja+=s("0x"+ga.slice(ka,z));}else u();}else{if(ia=='"')break;ja+=ia;z++;}}if(ga.charAt(z)=='"'){z++;return ja;}u();}else{ka=z;if(ia=="-"){ma=true;ia=ga.charAt(++z);}if(ia>="0"&&ia<="9"){if(ia=="0"&&(ia=ga.charAt(z+1),ia>="0"&&ia<="9"))u();ma=false;for(;z<ha&&(ia=ga.charAt(z),ia>="0"&&ia<="9");z++);if(ga.charAt(z)=="."){la=++z;for(;la<ha&&(ia=ga.charAt(la),ia>="0"&&ia<="9");la++);if(la==z)u();z=la;}ia=ga.charAt(z);if(ia=="e"||ia=="E"){ia=ga.charAt(++z);if(ia=="+"||ia=="-")z++;for(la=z;la<ha&&(ia=ga.charAt(la),ia>="0"&&ia<="9");la++);if(la==z)u();z=la;}return +ga.slice(ka,z);}if(ma)u();if(ga.slice(z,z+4)=="true"){z+=4;return true;}else if(ga.slice(z,z+5)=="false"){z+=5;return false;}else if(ga.slice(z,z+4)=="null"){z+=4;return null;}u();}}return "$";};w=function(ga){var ha,ia,ja;if(ga=="$")u();if(typeof ga=="string"){if(ga.charAt(0)=="@")return ga.slice(1);if(ga=="["){ha=[];for(;;ia||(ia=true)){ga=v();if(ga=="]")break;if(ia)if(ga==","){ga=v();if(ga=="]")u();}else u();if(ga==",")u();ha.push(w(ga));}return ha;}else if(ga=="{"){ha={};for(;;ia||(ia=true)){ga=v();if(ga=="}")break;if(ia)if(ga==","){ga=v();if(ga=="}")u();}else u();if(ga==","||typeof ga!="string"||ga.charAt(0)!="@"||v()!=":")u();ha[ga.slice(1)]=w(v());}return ha;}u();}return ga;};y=function(ga,ha,ia){var ja=x(ga,ha,ia);if(ja===j){delete ga[ha];}else ga[ha]=ja;};x=function(ga,ha,ia){var ja=ga[ha],ka;if(typeof ja=="object"&&ja)if(g.call(ja)=="[object Array]"){for(ka=ja.length;ka--;)y(ja,ka,ia);}else i(ja,function(la){y(ja,la,ia);});return ia.call(ga,ha,ja);};k.parse=function(ga,ha){z=0;aa=ga;var ia=w(v());if(v()!="$")u();z=aa=null;return ha&&g.call(ha)=="[object Function]"?x((ba={},ba[""]=ia,ba),"",ha):ia;};}}}).call(this);});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error as well on one of our websites. I also see the error on other websites with the Facebook JS SDK, like http://fubar.com. Makes me think it's something with Facebook or Firefox.

Comment: I get this error with FF 24, but not with FF 28...

Comment: I get this error since FF 28 came out, and the locale for the FB SDK is hu_HU, so my guess is that this bug is caused by FB...

Comment: I use FF28 and get this bug

Answer (score 2):

I solved this same problem for myself after recently posting it as a Facebook bug on https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/729597157070762/ With FB's help I noticed the following unwanted browser extensions in Firefox: Searchme, Slick Savings, Amazon Shopping Assistant, and Ebay Shopping Assistant. Turns out these are essentially malware that effected Firefox, Safari, and Chrome on my Mac. They're made by a company called Spigot, Inc.

While searching for an effective means of virus removal I found this link http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-spigot/ which gives detailed instructions how to do so.

I hope this helps you kevin!

---

Unfortunately a month or so after my original answer (above) the same error and warnings came back for me but just as of `yesterday, 4/22/2014` they changed to these 5 warnings, instead:

1. `Content Security Policy:` allow directive is deprecated, use the equivalent

default-src directive instead

```
  ...conds();wa=na.getUTCMilliseconds();}na=(pa<=0||pa>=10000?(pa<0?"-":"+")+o(6,pa<0...
    all.js (line 27)
```

1. The X-Content-Security-Policy and X-Content-Security-Report-Only headers will be deprecated in the future. Please use the Content-Security-Policy and Content-Security-Report-Only headers with CSP spec compliant syntax instead.
2. "Content Security Policy: allow directive is deprecated, use the equivalent default-src directive instead"
3. "The X-Content-Security-Policy and X-Content-Security-Report-Only headers will be deprecated in the future. Please use the Content-Security-Policy and Content-Security-Report-Only headers with CSP spec compliant syntax instead."
4. `Use of getPreventDefault()` is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.

   `{href:function(a){return a.getAttribute("href")},type:function(a){return a.getAt`

   jquery.min.js (line 3)

My guess is that the errors/warnings are due to the way the Facebook like button is engineered and how it interacts with Firefox and other browsers. The change in warnings and errors to these new warnings seems to indicate that Facebook and or Mozilla are working on this issue and will hopefully fix it...???

---

`yesterday, 4/29/2014` This was officially classified as a Facebook known bug issue I created and is currently being addressed. Below is text from the FB email to me:

The bug you are subscribed to ["like button works but errors show onload in firebug "Content Security Policy: Failed to parse unrecognized source chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl""](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/729597157070762) has been updated:
Status has changed: Closed → Assigned

Hi All, We have managed to reproduce this issue and it appears to be a valid bug. We are assigning this to the appropriate team. This might take some time to fix but we will do our best to keep you updated on the progress of this bug as soon as we can. Thanks

---

`today, 5/07/2014` I just received an email from Facebook stating,

"Status has changed: Assigned → Fixed

This should now be resolved. Thanks for your patience."

Looks good on my end, no longer an issue.

Comment: This didn't help. I get the same error but don't have any extensions installed other than firebug. Same error in firefox in OSX and a clean Windows VM where there is definitely no malware installed.

Comment: Same - didn't help me either.

Comment: Same here, only firebug installed.

Answer (score 0):

FYI,

I recently encountered this issue while adding the Facebook javascript login while working in Firefox (28) Private browsing.

I noticed that my Firebug console would consistenly display

```
"Couldn't parse invalid source chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl" etc...
```

It wasn't until I closed my browser completely that this message went away.

This meant that while I was testing my app I would need to completely close out of my browser to refresh the application, not just my private windows but all windows and console log windows as well.

I did not test this in other browsers just Firefox 28.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all FF extensions, and started from clean FF 28 installation.

Installed firebug and user agent overrider add-ons and did not get this error.
Then, I changed user agent and an error shows up on some agents and does not on some.

Error shows up on following agents:

- Mac / chrome 32
- linux / chrome 32
- windows / chrome 32
- Android /    chrome 32